# Building clean Nuget2 repository gives error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I'm currently trying to build my own nuget repository (like nuget.org).

In order to do so, I had a look at [Nuget.Server](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server). But when running this solution it crashes at a few packages, that can be downloaded from nuget.org (e.g. opencart.entities 1.0.2).

It crashes in ServerPackageStore.cs, line 83:

```
var tasks = _repository
            .GetPackages()
            .Select(package => 
                TryAddServerPackageAsync(allPackages, package, enableDelisting, token))
            .ToList();
```

The function where the exception is thrown is GetPackages(), a function in the nuget-package nuget.core. In order to rewrite the function, accepting thrown Exceptions and just continue, I downloaded the source code from [Nuget2](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2) and tried to build it by cloning the repo and run build.cmd:

C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\NuGet2>.\build.cmd
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Target framework is v4.0. VisualStudioVersion is 14.0.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2719,5): 
error MSB3552: Resource file "..\..\NuGet.Client\src\NuGet.Core\NuGet.Frameworks\Strings.resx" cannot be found. 
[C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\NuGet2\src\Core\Core.csproj]
```

When trying to build it with Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Community edition, the same error occurs.

How can I build the Nuget2 repo or is there maybe another way to tackle my problem with the Nuget.Server?

Comment: The error is telling you it's looking for a resource file and it can't find it. Does the file exist?

Comment: The file doesn't exist but in the [Core.csproj](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.13/src/Core/Core.csproj) file it is defined (line: 25):
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\NuGet.Client\src\NuGet.Core\NuGet.Frameworks\Strings.resx">
      <Link>NuGet.Frameworks\Strings.resx</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I build the Nuget2 repo or is there maybe another way to
>   tackle my problem with the Nuget.Server?

You also need download the solution [NuGet.Client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/49234c230df0fc01868d8b90e667af89be8cc4f6) and unzip it to the folder `NuGet.Client` of your current solution.

When you download the solution NuGet2, you will find the folder `NuGet.Client` is empty. That is the reason why you got that error:

> "error MSB3552: Resource file
>   "....\NuGet.Client\src\NuGet.Core\NuGet.Frameworks\Strings.resx"
>   cannot be found."

To resolve this error, please download the NuGet.Client solution and unzip it, copy all contents in the folder `NuGet.Client-49234c230df0fc01868d8b90e667af89be8cc4f6` to the NuGet.Client folder, then build the project.

Hope this helps.